# Crystal reports export to excel cell merge issue

Tags: excel, crystal-reports, export

When I export from Crystal Reports, any fields that are marked as `Can Grow` are merged with  an otherwise blank row below them.

This completely messes up my sorting. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest another way: choose **ExportFormatType.ExcelRecord instead of ExportFormatType.Excel**. The xls file will be created without formatting.

If actually the user is exporting report using ReportViewer Toolbar Export button you can:

- Replace the CrystalReportViewer Control with the **[ReportExporter](http://devlibrary.businessobjects.com/businessobjectsxi/en/en/CrystalReports_dotNET_SDK/crystalreports_net_doc/doc/crsdk_net_doc/html/crtsktutorialsotherreportexporterreplace.htm)** Control. It will export the report in the format you choose.

Or hide Export button from toolbar and put in the page buttons that exports programmatically

- Call **[ExportToHttpResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc411349%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)** method

`CrystalReportSource1.ReportDocument.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.ExcelRecord, this.Response  , false, "report.xls");`

- Call **[ExportToDisk](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms225954%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)** method

`reportDocument.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.ExcelRecord, "report.xls");`

- **Export dataset** to excel (Look at [Ahmed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153199/crystal-reports-export-to-excel-cell-merge-issue/3165645#3165645))

You can choose the way that best fits your needs, but you must **try if it works with the runtime you use either in development or in release server**.

*ExportFormatType.ExcelRecord* means that is generated an xls file, without formatting. If you set *ExportFormatType.Excel* fields that are marked as "Can Grow" are merged with an otherwise blank row below them.

Answer (score 2):

I always get a lot of problems while exporting crystal report to excel, I always got the same problem you have encountered.
I solved that problem by exporting dataset (report datasource) directly to excel, this solved all the issues, I've encountered.

Please refer to this link for [Export a Dataset to Excel](http://tim.mackey.ie/HowtoExportADatasetToExcelCAspnet.aspx).