# Export unformatted Excel data from Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I need to export excel file with crystal report.

Is there any way to export data only without formatting by using code?

Comment: Please specify more details. In crystal report there are inbuilt functionality to export report in excel/pdf.

Comment: noa have you tried my solution?

Comment: I added some options, i have used an instance of ExcelFormatOptions class instead of using ExportFormatType.ExcelRecord directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export data shown in the report without formatting, in different ways:

1- Replace the CrystalReportViewer Control with the **[ReportExporter](http://devlibrary.businessobjects.com/businessobjectsxi/en/en/CrystalReports_dotNET_SDK/crystalreports_net_doc/doc/crsdk_net_doc/html/crtsktutorialsotherreportexporterreplace.htm)** Control. It will export the report in the format you choose.

2- Call **[ExportToHttpResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc411349%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)** method

```
CrystalReportSource1.ReportDocument.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.ExcelRecord, this.Response  , false, "report.xls");`
```

3- Call **[ExportToDisk](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms225954%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)** method

```
reportDocument.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.ExcelRecord, "report.xls");
```

4- **Export dataset** to excel (Look at [Ahmed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153199/crystal-reports-export-to-excel-cell-merge-issue/3165645#3165645))

You can choose the way that best fits your needs, but you must **try if it works with the runtime you use either in development or in release server**.

*ExportFormatType.ExcelRecord* means that is generated an xls file, without formatting. If you set *ExportFormatType.Excel* fields that are marked as "Can Grow" are merged with an otherwise blank row below them..

Comment: anouar204, which way did you choose?