# Removing all page breaks from a Crystal Reports 2016 v14 -> Excel export

Tags: excel, crystal-reports

I haven't dusted off Crystal in a while and have a client who has a pretty report (with page breaks in all the right places).  The problem is they really want to export the report to one big Excel file and

We have it so that the page header only exports once ... but we can't stop repeating group headers from happening when it appears Crystal thinks it should "page break" the output data.

I don't see any way in the Excel export or on detail or page sections to "ignore page breaks" ... is this an option in any way?

Alternatively I could just do a SQL query for them but then I am teaching them a new tool or approach.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try ExportFormatType.ExcelRecord instead of ExportFormatType.Excel ? That way it exports without formatting .

See more information on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8575767/10191493).

Comment: If the export is being done manually from a Crystal Report Reader by clicking the Export button the export option needed will say "Data Only" next to the Excel version for the export.  The `ExportFormatType.ExcelRecord` is for when exporting via VB or C# code.

Answer (score 0):

If the purposal answer of @TheOne__ do work for you, you may try what i usually do:

1. Pass a parameter do the report indicating if it is for Excel.
2. Use that parameter combined to page and group counter to suppress headers and avoid "new page before" and "new page after" on sections.

For example, suppose the parameter is named {?Excel}.

Create a formula to "suppress" the "page header" like this:

```
{?Excel} and pagenumber > 1
```

So, the page header will be printed just once.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't looking to do this programmatically ... so I just increased the page length to the max which eliminated all the use cases that my client was concerned about.

Good to have these options as a backup if more use cases pop up.