# Misalignment in fields when exporting crystal report to excel

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel, crystal-reports

I have this crosstab in my crystal report, alignment is fine whenever I'd generate it thru front-end. This is how it looked like:

[image]

But after exporting the report to excel, the details in the Staff ID messes up the alignment, I tried removing it, then export it, the alignment is fine, but whenever the Staff ID is included, it messes up the alignment in excel file. Here's how it looked like:

[image]

Comment: are both cells getting merged?

Comment: @Siva which cells are you pertaining to?

Comment: staff ID... is getting merged in excel export

Comment: the detail for staff id is merging with Position column. Staff ID detail must only be in row 4 column M, but it merges with column N as well @Siva

Comment: @Siva yes thats my question, i wonder why it merges with column N, but my crystal report is fine and my whenever I generate it thru front-end, its aligned.

Comment: I would suggest you to export the report with `data only option` and not with other option and let me know how it goes... I don't see any other issue other that this.. Also if possible let me know what all export options you see

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is known issue or I say this is the functionality. While export to excel, it ask option(I was done quite long time ago, so not exactly at right now) 1. with format 2. without format.

Default is with format and we can not control (it render as per its logic which is unknown at design time). The problem with `can grow` or `auto-width` option of the fields. Whenever you set true, will expand with merge.

Just check how to resolve :

http://www.forumtopics.com/busobj/viewtopic.php?p=803623

[Crystal reports export to excel cell merge issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153199/crystal-reports-export-to-excel-cell-merge-issue)

http://www.forumtopics.com/busobj/viewtopic.php?p=885543

http://businessintelligence.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/businessobjects-dev-l/export-to-excel-causes-merged-cells-4640546

Comment: my header and my field are of the same sizes and alignment, and my can grow property is set to false. That is why I wonder why with the export of report there is misalignment of cells.

Comment: is the above link helping to you?

Comment: nope, because my can grow property is set to false. I dont have here in visual studio the autofit width, i think it is for other tools

Comment: Crystal Reports export to excel are not always the best and easy to get around. Sometimes you need to place dummy empty text fields for CR to force that space.